# php and soap... possible to catch errors?

Tags: php, soap

The script runs on php 4 with nusoap library

```
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new soapclient("some-url",true);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) 
{
header("Location: error-page");
exit();
}
```

My question is this: in case an error is detected, is it possible to wait for 1-2 secs ( something like sleep(2); ) and then try to re-enable the soap connection? And for future reference... how can i get all possible errors and build cases for them? For example for some errors wait to re-initialize the connection, for some other errors, log to db the reason, and for the rest just redirect to a general error page.

Answer (score 1):

You do know how to program, right? Just drop the code into a loop:

```
$retries = 3; // how many times to retry the connection
$sleep   = 2; // number of seconds to sleep in-between retries

$i = 1;
while (TRUE) {

    $client = new soapclient("some-url",true);

    if ( ! $client->getError()) {
        break; // break out of the loop on success
    } elseif ($i === $retries) {
        header("Location: error-page");
        exit();
    }

    sleep($sleep);
    ++$i;
}
```